# Set button margin with auto window size

Tags: c#, wpf

I've created a simple custom messagebox that automatically scales depending on the length of the text to be displayed :

```
public partial class CustomMessageBox : Window
{
    public CustomMessageBox(string title, string text)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
        label.Content = text;
        Title = title;
    }

    public static void Show(string title, string text)
    {
        CustomMessageBox box = new CustomMessageBox(title, text);
        box.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight;
        box.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }
}
```

This works nicely however my button is clamping to the bottom side of the window because the window automatically scales :

[image: clamping]

And the button seems to be moving once the message gets longer :

[image: moving button]

How would I make sure the button stays centered and have a margin of around 10px from the bottom so it doesn't look that clamped?

I tried to set the `Margin` manually but that doesn't seem to work.

XAML (largely generated by the designer) :

```
<Window x:Class="RapidEvent.CustomMessageBox"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RapidEvent"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Background="{DynamicResource WindowBackgroundBrush}"
        Title="" Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <Label x:Name="label" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="13px" RenderTransformOrigin="0.392,0.486"/>
            <Button x:Name="button" x:FieldModifier="public" IsDefault="True" Content="_Ok" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="110,40,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" Height="21" Click="button_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Did you try with _HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,40,0,10"_

Comment: @Steve That seemed to work. And it was so easy too.. thanks :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change your `StackPanel` to a `Grid` and the `HorizonalAlignment` of your button to `Center` and take off all but the bottom margin. You'll also need to set the `VerticalAlignment` to `Bottom`. You also need to put the button on row 1.

This way the button will be clamped to the bottom of the dialog and always centred.

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label x:Name="label" Content=""
               HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,0"
               VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="13px"
               RenderTransformOrigin="0.392,0.486"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" x:Name="button" x:FieldModifier="public"
                IsDefault="True" Content="_Ok"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,20"
                VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="80" Height="21"/>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use grid instead of StackPanel:

```
   <Grid >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <telerik:Label x:Name="label" Content="LSFFD" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="13px" RenderTransformOrigin="0.392,0.486"/>
                <Button Grid.Row="1" x:Name="button" x:FieldModifier="public"  Content="_Ok" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0 0 0 10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="80" Height="21" Click="button_Click"/>

        </Grid>
```